# Using transactions with subsonic

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, subsonic, transactions

In my web application I've to keep audit of the user actions. So whenever user takes an action I update the object on which action is taken and keep audit trail of that action.

Now If I first modify the object and then update audit trail but the audit trail fails then what?

Obviously I need to roll-back changes to modified object. I can use Sql-Transactions in simple application, but I'm using Subsonic to talk to db. How I can handle the situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like:

```
Using ts As New System.Transactions.TransactionScope()
  Using sharedConnectionScope As New SubSonic.SharedDbConnectionScope()

' Do your individual saves here

' If all OK
      ts.Complete()

   End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I can confirm TransactionScope works correctly with SubSonic, and does rollback transactions correctly.

Comment: Thanks @kevinw and @bnkdev. I'm using C# so I'll post the code in C# also so it can be readily used by others. Also wouldn't you put the individual saves or actions inside try/catch so it is easier to know if all Ok or not?

Answer (score 15):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910863/using-transactions-with-subsonic/911069#911069) given by [@Kevinw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108853/kevinw) is perfectly okay. I'm posting this just as translation of his answer to C# code. I'm not using comments as it will not format code :) Also I'm using try/catch to know if transaction should complete or be rolled back.

```
using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (SharedDbConnectionScope scs = new SharedDbConnectionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            //do your stuff like saving multiple objects etc. here 

            //everything should be completed nicely before you reach this
            //line if not throw exception and don't reach to line below
            ts.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ts.Dispose(); //Don't need this as using will take care of it.
            //Do stuff with exception or throw it to caller
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `ts.Dispose()` inside the catch-clause is not required as the using statement will take care of it anyway. In the general case, it could even cause problems as `SharedDbConnectionScope` or other transaction aware code launched inside the transaction scope might depend on being disposed before the enclosing transaction scope is disposed.

Comment: @OskarBerggren commented it.

Comment: Does this also handle operations inside a stored procedure? Say I am calling multiple sps which do CRUD operations, will this revert everything?

Comment: @GeomanYabes yes transactions get passed on to the MS SQL server ( if you are using that). Not sure about other database servers.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  If I put the `SharedDbConnectionScope` outside the changes are visibles in the database before `ts.Complete()`.  Putting it inside blocks the server until the operation is done.

Comment: Can anyone enlighten me with this? So no other transactions will be catered unless the current transaction completes? i.e. You have a long-running transaction, other users can't interact with the database until the transaction finishes?